# Этимология слова "тусовка"

Tags: жаргон, этимология

Откуда в молодежном сленге взялось слово "тусовка" (а сейчас уже и не только молодежном)? Каково его происхождение?

Comment: Из блатного сленга

Comment: DocentI, я в балете - как свин в цитрусовых, можно подробнее?
Какие-то смутеые ассоциации действительно есть, но не более...

Comment: Если бы я знала, написала бы ответ, а не комментарий. Источник - ОБС (одна баба сказала). Что-то где-то слышала. Может, по телевизору. Может, это была искусственная идея, призванная привнести отрицательное отношение к самому этому образу жизни?  

Интернет не подтверждает

Answer (score 3):

Не долго над этим раздумывал, так что не принимайте близко к сердцу. Кажется, что этимологически происходит от "тасовки" карт, а вследствие, быть может, так стали называть развлекательные посиделки (в начале - на зоне, за чашечкой чифиря, а после - и в широких слоях общества).
Ваш верный слуга - Евгений)

Comment: Вполне  возможно.

Answer (score 0):

У **[Марины Королёвой](https://rg.ru/2012/04/05/tusovka.html)** есть версия происхождения бывшего жаргонизма:

> Возможно, тусовка происходит от французского tous, то есть "все"
>   (например, tous sont venus - все пришли).

[Другие версии](http://playroom.ru/proishozhdenie-slova-tusovka/) мне представляются недостоверными.

А! [Ещё одна](http://ru-etymology.livejournal.com/813449.html), симпатичная:

> В шведском языке есть слово tusen - тысяча. Может, оно?

Или:

> Если французское слово, то не tous (все), а tas (куча)...

Не вполне компетентный [источник](http://insamara.ru/slovo/?PAGE_NAME=read&FID=18&TID=12) повествует:

> Широко употребительное сейчас слово "тусовка" (чаще называющее место
>   проведения досуга молодёжи и само общение молодёжи с целью отдыха,
>   развлечений) в общеуголовном арго обозначало "сбор преступников для
>   решения организационных вопросов".

Answer (score 0):

При игре в карты 9 из 10 человек (а то и 14 из 15) говорили ТУСУЙ (а не ТАСУЙ) карты. От этого неверного произношения и пошла ТУСОВКА - перемешивание, только не карт, а людей.

Comment: Это надо принять как единственную достоверную версию?